# Почему мы используем ссылки на другие объекты классов?

Tags: java, классы, ссылки

Например, что-то типа этого:

```
Example obj = new Demo();
```

Comment: Почитайте про полиморфизм, интерфейсы и их наследников.

Comment: в чем именно вопрос?

Comment: Потому что это помогает решить задачу.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, в этом примере класс `Demo` является подклассом `Example` или же реализует его, если это интерфейс. Причина — полиморфизм, что позволяет обобщить один и тот же алгоритм на объекты, соответствующие некоторому контракту.

Возможные реализации Demo и Example:

```java
class Example {
}

class Demo extends Example {
}
```

```java
interface Example {
}

class Demo implements Example {
}
```